# Visual Studio Code - Add option(s) in 'select default shell' list on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use **various shells in VSCode terminal**, eg. **Git Bash**. I can set it in `settings.json` with `terminal.integrated.shell.windows`, but if I select **CMD** as default subsequently, that setting will get replaced.  And if I add another `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` to `bash.exe`, I'm stuck with bash, can't change default shell, seems logical anyway if **VSCode** only replaces the 1st setting, but read the last same setting value.

The problem is there's no Bash existed in the "select default shell" list, and my question is **how to add that**?

I have installed latest (2.22.0) 64-bit version of Git for Windows, and hoped it would add the necessary env/reg etc for that, but no.

Even though this should be version independent, nevertheless here's my VSCode About:

> Version: 1.35.1 (user setup)
>
> Commit: c7d83e57cd18f18026a8162d042843bda1bcf21f
>
> Date: 2019-06-12T14:30:02.622Z
>
> Electron: 3.1.8
>
> Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
>
> Node.js: 10.2.0
>
> V8: 6.6.346.32
>
> OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.10240

Please. I know there are similar questions, but they don't really solve my problem.  However, the correct answer to my question will solve theirs.

Answer (score 2):

[image]
If your question is how to add more terminal shells to `Terminal:Select Default Shell`, I dont think thats easily possible.

But you can use `Shell Launcher` plugin to add more shells and launch them in your integrated terminal. Below is a screen shot where I added Julia to the list.
[image]

### Installation:

1. Go to Extensions and add `Shell launcher`. 
   [image]
2. Go to settings(Ctrl+,) and search for `Shell Launcher` and edit for your platform.
   [image]
3. Add your shell to the list
   [image]
4. You can launch this by F1(Command Pallete) -> `Shell Launcher`
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

My alternative solution is to use the "**terminal.external.windowsExec**" setting for non-default Windows shell.  But you can only have one such setting!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same question, and have looked through all of the documentation, and every article I can find on the subject, and haven't found the answer. I found a terminal launcher extension, but that creates a separate menu. There must be a json file somewhere that has the list of choices for the Select Default Shell menu. Does anyone know how to update that menu?

I did some more testing on this. On the Mac version (and I assume the linux version), there is a file called /etc/shells that is used to determine what to put in the menu. If there is a similar file on Windows, I'm not sure what it would be called or where it would be.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on Linux who cannot seem to find the option at all, uninstall VS Code and reinstall the latest version from the website.

I spent so much time with the same issue but the reason was that I had installed it from the pop shop on my pop OS (Linux).

Answer (score -1):

The *Select Default Shell* command just list the shells that can be found from your %PATH% environment variable. Add the shell and restart VSCode to see it.

Here is to [add a new path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

Remember that you can always start a shell from another one. Just type `bash` from inside CMD.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  That's the first thing I tried.  Also, I started vscode in cmd and double confirm that the path is set in %PATH%!