# Add git bash to default shells list in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Win10 with WSL installed. The only default shells available to me are - `cmd`, `powershell` and `wsl`. I'd like to add `git bash` as one of the possible default choices in dropdown menu. I managed to make `git bash` work in VSCode by changing `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` path in the `settings.json`, but `git bash` still doesn't appear in the default shells available menu.

As far as I understand, the problem is that after I installed WSL, now I have 2 `bash.exe` and VSCode doesn't want to add the second one. All `PATH` variables are set correctly.
[image]

> `where bash`
> `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe`
> `D:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

Can I somehow add git bash to the default shells list in VSCode?

Comment: Tried to use this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868598/visual-studio-code-add-options-in-select-default-shell-list-on-windows. Didn't help. Also tried to use `bash` within `cmd/powershell` got `wsl` shell as a result. What's really strangle is that extension `shellLauncher` correctly finds all shells (`git` included in json), but doens't show it in dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, nvm, seems like it was done intentionally - https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72200

If you have `git` installed on another drive, you won't be able to add it to defaults.